# Python: Trouble finding element inside div xmlns

Tags: python, selenium

I'm attempting to automate some work with selenium and I'm having issues sending keys to the input id when attempting to login and I'm wondering if I'm in over my head.

I've tried locating the element by xpath, id as well as class, with no luck. I've also tried to wait to make sure the element is visible with no luck. Perhaps it's due to the `div xmlns`is inside a `body xmlns`, resulting in the elements within the `div xmlns` initially not being visible? If so, how do I go about making the input box visible?

This is basically how far I've come:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# website url
url = "https://tx-production-eu-web.production.eu1.tx.klarna.net/radix/"

# driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\ahmed.khairouni\Desktop\driver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

# wait for page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

#locate element and insert text into textbox
username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "wf_139389")))
search_input.send_keys('username')
```

Linked you can find part of the web code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPN1E.jpg

Appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post the stack trace of the error

Comment: @Sureshmani apologies for not including it the in OP: ```raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here might be the `input` is using a dynamic ID, so finding by ID may not work. I also noticed you are locating `username`, but then you are sending keys to `search_input`, which does not seem to exist in your code. That may be causing your issue, unless you made a typo in this question.

You could try using an XPath to locate the `username` input:

```
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class, 'rwt-regular-value')]")))

username.send_keys('username')
```